# ajax update not working

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax, combobox, updatepanel

I am trying to get a combobox to update with the correct value when a button has been clicked.

So when the user chooses a year in the combobox then enters a day in the 'HolidayYearAllocation' input box and clicks the button, the combobox called 'AssignUserHoliday' needs to update with the year selected.

Here is the code  where i select the year, and then enter an amount and click the button

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateBulkHoliday" runat="server" class="BulkHolidayAllocation">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="BulkHolidayAllocationHeader">
      <asp:Label ID="lbl_bulkholidayallocationheader" runat="server" Text="Bulk Holiday Allocation" />
    </div>
    <div class="SelectYearHolidayAllocation">
      <asp:Label ID="lbl_selectyearholidayallocation" runat="server" Text="Select Year" CssClass="applicationfont" />
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_selectyearholidayallocation" runat="server" CssClass="smallinputbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="EnterYearHolidayAllocation">
      <asp:Label ID="lbl_enteryearholidayallocation" runat="server" Text="Enter Amount of Days" CssClass="applicationfont" />
      <input id="txt_enteryearholidayallocation" runat="server" class="smallinputbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="SubmitYearHolidayAllocation">
      <input id="btn_submityearholidayallocation" runat="server" type="button" class="Button" value="Add" onserverclick="btn_submityearholidayallocation_ServerClick" />
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the update panel wrapped around the code i want to update after button click.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="Update" runat="Server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="UserSettingsSection2">
      <div class="AssignUserHoliday">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_assignuserholiday" runat="server" Text="Assign User Holiday" CssClass="applicationfont" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_assignuserholiday" runat="server" CssClass="smallinputbox" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnDataBound="ddl_assignuserholiday_DataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_assignuserholiday_SelectedIndexChanged" />
      </div>
      <div class="SetNewUserHoliday">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_setnewuserholiday" runat="server" Text="New Holiday Amount" CssClass="applicationfont" />
        <input id="txt_setnewuserholiday" runat="server" class="smallinputbox" />
      </div>
      <div class="SubmitNewUserHoliday">
        <input id="btn_submitnewuserholiday" runat="server" class="Button" type="button" value="Change" visible="false" onserverclick="btn_submitnewuserholiday_ServerClick" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add following attribute to both update panel `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and call `Update.Update()` in the `btn_submityearholidayallocation_ServerClick` method once you have assigned the values to the controls in the second panel.

Comment: Update.Update() doesn't work for me is there a namespace I need?

Comment: Are you getting compliation errors? Or the event just doesn't fire?

Comment: It cant find the first Update part just has the red line under it, saying it does not exist.

Comment: I have found the Update was me being stupid, but when i run it still doesn't work.

Comment: The first part of Update is the id of your first update panel. Make sure you have a declaration in the designer for the first update panel

Comment: And I guess you have ScriptManager declared on the page?

Comment: I have done it! The reason was that I wasn't clearing the itemsource of the combobox and repopulating in the correct place, so when I moved it and updated the UpdatePanel it worked! Thanks